# jQuery: Ajax success data render multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

I am using ajax call re-render filter data (html view). It works perfect with single output as json but when I tries to get HTML render it duplicate multiple times  below is the following code

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/url",
                data: { options } 
            }).done(function(data){                     
                if(data.status == 'success') {
                    jQuery('.job-collection')[0].reset();
                }
                 jQuery('.job-collection').html(data.output);
            });
```

How to show html received only once?

Comment: try to use id instead of class, this may be issue.

Comment: what is your response data exactly? *check in* `inspector -> network` tab